# Adding dynamic height with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to calculate available height of an element and add it to a style via jQuery. How to I add the var of the height? Here's where I am at the moment:

```
var scrolH = $("#box").height() - $(".alert").height() - 100;
$("#container").css({"overflow-y":"scroll", "height": scrolH + "px"});
```

Comment: What doesn't work about your current code? Try removing the ` + "px"` bit.

Comment: Looks good enough to me. What's the problem?

Comment: Can you give a simplified example of the html, css, and jquery working together?  That would help in determining what the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think You should do:

```
 $("#container").height(scrolH);
 $("#container").css({"overflow-y":"scroll"});
```

Answer (score 1):

Even a little bit shorter

```
$("#container").height(scrolH).css({"overflow-y":"scroll"});
```